# How to in Git, clone a remote (GitHub) repository from a specifed date

Tags: git, github

I'm trying to clone a git repository from a certain date.  Even if this is not possible.  Is it possible to clone the git repository and then roll it back to a certain date?

Example: my repository has been updated since May 2010, but I'd like to get the version from June 5th.  I'd like to run the following command:

```
git clone git@github.com:projectfolder -date 06-05-2010
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Cloning the repository will give you the entire commit history of all the source code.

You need only scroll back through `git log` and find the desired commit on your target date. Running `git checkout SHA` where `SHA` is the commit hash will give you the state of the source code on that date.

edit:

`git log --since=2010-06-05 --until=2010-06-06` will help narrow it down!

Comment: Your branch does not appear to have any commits yet. How do I set branch to default fetched from remote?

Answer (score 6):

```
git clone git@github.com:projectfolder
git reset --hard $(git rev-list -1 $(git rev-parse --until=2010-06-06) master)
```

Answer (score 5):

Maybe something like this:

`git log --since=2010-06-05 --until=2010-06-05`

Find one of the commit ids you like there then do a `git checkout <checkout id>`

Comment: Damn. I was editing my answer to add that exact command when you answered!

Comment: hehe, happens to the best of us :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use git's revert command to revert every commit back to the date you are looking for, or you can just create a a new branch at the commit you are interested in.

Comment: Reverting will abandon any newer history which is never a good option. Branching off of the commit immensely preferred to revert.

Comment: This is destructive and there's much better ways of doing it.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following commits:

```
5 May (A) -- 7 May -- master (current)
5 May (B) -- 7 May /
```

There is no way git can figure out whether you want commit `A` or `B`. So, you should use `git log` or `gitk` to get the SHA1 of the commit from that date you want and then `git checkout` it.

Answer (score 0):

Hit the same issue, had to share a git repo with history until a specific point in time, in my case July 4th, 2023. I'm sure there's an even cleaner / cleverer way to do this, but I didn't see any posted here, so figured I'd share what I ended up doing:

```
$ git clone <repo>
```

Will checkout the repo with full history, as multiple folks have noted.

```
$ pushd <checked-out-repo-name>
$ git log --until=<your date, e.g. 2023-07-04>
```

Will show you the git history leading up to your date, the latest commit being the last submitted until then.

```
$ git checkout <latest-commit-id>
$ git push <remote> HEAD:refs/heads/<your-branch-name>
```

Push a reasonably named branch on top of the latest commit from that date.

```
$ popd
$ rm -rf <checked_out_repo_name>

... wait a second to a minute for the server to sync ...

$ git clone -b <your-branch-name> --single-branch <repo>
```

That'll give you a repo with a single branch starting with the commit on that date. I'm sure you can play around with the final `git clone` command's parameters to suit your particular needs.

```
$ pushd <checked-out-repo-name>
$ git push <remote> --delete <your-branch-name>
```

Optionally, running the command above will delete the temporary branch you created, if you want to clean up afterwards.

Comment: This is a valid use-case.  Everyone will say "don't destroy commits in the repo".  But then you have a legal court case where the other party is entitled to look at source code with history in a specific date range.  And you absolutely want to destroy the history in the cloned repo.