# Is it possible to do a shallow git clone based on datetime?

Tags: git, date, git-clone

I know I can do a shallow clone by specifying the `--depth` flag. However, this takes in an integer as its value. Is there any way to have the identical behavior with a `datetime`? I do not wish to clone the entire repository and checkout a previous state.

Comment: It's already discussed [here][1]. Did you go through it?


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3790671/how-to-in-git-clone-a-remote-github-repository-from-a-specifed-date

Comment: Yes, but it involved having the repository cloned already. The reason is that I''m building a script that does not require the entire history of the repository. The cloning is the actual bottleneck in terms of runtime right now.

Comment: The only idea that comes to my mind is "get the depth by grep-ping the logs corresponding to the date" and specify it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Why yes it is. At least only with Git 2.11 (Q4 2016)

See [commit cccf74e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/cccf74e2da85808478c784e403a69bbfe2b9f518), [commit 079aa97](https://github.com/git/git/commit/079aa97e24daff1329f041e00ba621b0afd59163), [commit 2997178](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2997178ee63c76a4c449f35f299e20b32956795a), [commit cdc3727](https://github.com/git/git/commit/cdc37277f904ff5c832f04db9e799bccd9672ea5), [commit 859e5df](https://github.com/git/git/commit/859e5df916cc3f3cba920c527f485ffaf6d7efa9), [commit a45a260](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a45a260086b395729e3c26c9680602e1352184b5), [commit 269a7a8](https://github.com/git/git/commit/269a7a831636b7c7a453f6621fc8b440ff28a408), [commit 41da711](https://github.com/git/git/commit/41da7111f2c825ee0dcd319ec246a84b5ca0fd21), [commit 6d43a0c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6d43a0cefd769c650bd114f41434ef5a7aa998e7), [commit 994c2aa](https://github.com/git/git/commit/994c2aaf31e1f8e8e69f86324e585620fee68c82), [commit 508ea88](https://github.com/git/git/commit/508ea88226bbdd25ac0aac4f9c8a65a2c3b5be5c), [commit 569e554](https://github.com/git/git/commit/569e554be9cb88047d9f2752750e0c260241f446), [commit 3d9ff4d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3d9ff4d736475bc74ed249c579b3ad7322e22b85), [commit 79891cb](https://github.com/git/git/commit/79891cb90a4e5b2680308ba2b757a218b9aaa14c), [commit 1dd73e2](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1dd73e20d72921fe81a881a9f6cff6d02eca8146), [commit 0d789a5](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0d789a5bc1aeef2d6d0d3120efc4b85766a0a327), [commit 45a3e52](https://github.com/git/git/commit/45a3e52641fd58c2ebaba2fd2a03308fd6ab8a0a), [commit 3f0f662](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3f0f6624f554a663ca0c83fd80f769dc9cef93e2), [commit 7fcbd37](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7fcbd37f9c1b7413b408d0223344d070613777ac), [commit 6e414e3](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6e414e30fd12460d7a7ba3ce67d20aa82a41a737) (12 Jun 2016) by [Nguyễn Thái Ngọc Duy (`pclouds`)](https://github.com/pclouds).
Helped-by: [Duy Nguyen (`pclouds`)](https://github.com/pclouds), [Eric Sunshine (`sunshineco`)](https://github.com/sunshineco), and [Junio C Hamano (`gitster`)](https://github.com/gitster).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit a460ea4](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a460ea4a3cb1dad253604b5e2aeaa161637453a9), 10 Oct 2016)</sup>

[`git clone`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/994c2aaf31e1f8e8e69f86324e585620fee68c82/Documentation/git-clone.txt#L196-L197) now includes:

```
--shallow-since=<date>:
```

> Create a shallow clone with a history after the specified time.

The date format should be one of the [formats presented in `git log`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#Documentation/git-log.txt---dateltformatgt).
Although the tests show raw dates:

```sh
cd shallow-since &&
GIT_COMMITTER_DATE="100000000 +0700" git commit --allow-empty -m one &&
GIT_COMMITTER_DATE="200000000 +0700" git commit --allow-empty -m two &&
GIT_COMMITTER_DATE="300000000 +0700" git commit --allow-empty -m three &&
git clone --shallow-since "300000000 +0700" "file://$(pwd)/." ../shallow11 &&
git -C ../shallow11 log --pretty=tformat:%s HEAD >actual &&
echo three >expected &&
test_cmp expected actual
```

"raw date" means: date as seconds since the epoch (1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC), followed by a space, and then the timezone as an offset from UTC (a + or - with four digits; the first two are hours, and the second two are minutes).

Comment: what's the right way to interpret `"100000000 +0700"`? 100000000 is `1973-03-03 09:46:40`, does the string mean `1973-03-03 09:46:40` at +0700, which is equivalent to `1973-03-03 02:46:40` at UTC?

Comment: @zyxue Yes, it is a Unix timestamp (https://www.silisoftware.com/tools/date.php?inputdate=100000000+%2B0700&inputformat=unix). The idea is to quickly create 3 commits, from oldest to newest, and 100M, 200M, 300M is an easy way to ensure that oldest-to-newest list of commit dates.